# Cannot import android.hardware.camera2

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to import android.hardware.camera2.*; to my project but android studio cant find it. It only shows android.hardware.Camera and android.graphics.Camera. My compile sdk version is also 23 so I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because there is no Java class in Android named android.hardware.Camera2. There is a Java package named android.hardware.camera2. You are welcome to use classes out of that Java package, such as android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager, via import statements like:

```
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
```